# How make child components of a child component have refs that the first-level child can use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

If I have the following JSX, the `Child`'s `refs` are empty:

```
<Parent>
    <Child ref="first">
        <GrandChild ref="parentSeesThisNotChild" />
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

I want the `Child` component to get the `GrandChild` in its `refs`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify the `Child` component code:

```
const Child = React.createClass({
  render() {
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        ref: child.ref,
      });
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Child</h1>
        {childrenWithProps}
      </div>
    )
  },
});
```